# Deploy React JS SPA in Openshift

Tags: reactjs, openshift

I have build a React JS app and triggered `yarn build` command. Its builded successfully and if I run `yarn global add serve`, its working perfectly on `http://localhost:5000`. After that I tried below link to deploy this code to OpenShift.
[OpenShift Deployment](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/04/modern-web-apps-openshift-part-1/)

According to the document, I tried to run `npx nodeshift --strictSSL=false --dockerImage=bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-web-app --imageTag=10.13.0 --build.env YARN_ENABLED=true --expose`

Then I got this log -

```
npx: installed 216 in 37.284s
kubernetes-client deprecated require('kubernetes-client').config, use require('kubernetes-client/backends/request').config. ..\..\Users\RITUPARNABHATTACHARY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\11068\node_modules\nodeshift\node_modules\openshift-rest-client\lib\openshift-rest-client.js:25:35
kubernetes-client deprecated require('kubernetes-client').config, use require('kubernetes-client/backends/request').config. ..\..\Users\RITUPARNABHATTACHARY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\11068\node_modules\nodeshift\node_modules\openshift-rest-client\index.js:23:39
2019-12-21T11:58:07.841Z INFO loading configuration
kubernetes-client deprecated fromKubeconfig see https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/blob/master/merging-with-kubernetes.md#request-kubeconfig- ..\..\Users\RITUPARNABHATTACHARY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\11068\node_modules\nodeshift\lib\nodeshift-config.js:35:32
2019-12-21T11:58:07.882Z INFO using namespace smart-learner at https://c101-e.jp-tok.containers.cloud.ibm.com:30512
kubernetes-client deprecated Client({ config }), see https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/blob/master/merging-with-kubernetes.md ..\..\Users\RITUPARNABHATTACHARY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\11068\node_modules\nodeshift\node_modules\openshift-rest-client\lib\openshift-rest-client.js:95:18
kubernetes-client deprecated Request() without a .kubeconfig option, see https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/blob/master/merging-with-kubernetes.md ..\..\Users\RITUPARNABHATTACHARY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\11068\node_modules\nodeshift\node_modules\kubernetes-client\lib\swagger-client.js:200:19
2019-12-21T11:58:07.928Z WARNING a file property was not found in your package.json, archiving the current directory.
2019-12-21T11:58:07.929Z INFO creating archive of .gitignore, build, Dockerfile, package-lock.json, package.json, public, README.md, src, yarn.lock
2019-12-21T11:58:09.001Z INFO using existing build configuration smartlearner-s2i
2019-12-21T11:58:09.377Z INFO using existing image stream smartlearner
2019-12-21T11:58:09.378Z INFO uploading binary archive C:\ReactAPP\smartlearner/tmp/nodeshift/build/archive.tar
2019-12-21T11:58:15.825Z INFO binary upload complete
2019-12-21T11:58:15.828Z INFO waiting for build to finish
kubernetes-client deprecated .getStream use .getByteStream, see https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/blob/master/merging-with-kubernetes.md ..\..\Users\RITUPARNABHATTACHARY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\11068\node_modules\nodeshift\lib\build-watcher.js:56:107
2019-12-21T11:58:19.798Z TRACE Using bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-web-app:10.x as the s2i builder image
2019-12-21T11:58:20.550Z TRACE ls: cannot access /tmp/src/node_modules: No such file or directory
2019-12-21T11:58:20.564Z TRACE ---> Installing application source
2019-12-21T11:58:20.585Z TRACE ---> Building your Web Application from source
2019-12-21T11:58:20.592Z TRACE Current git config
2019-12-21T11:58:20.620Z TRACE url.https://github.com.insteadof=git@github.com:
2019-12-21T11:58:20.629Z TRACE url.https://.insteadof=ssh://
2019-12-21T11:58:20.629Z TRACE url.https://github.com.insteadof=ssh://git@github.com
2019-12-21T11:58:20.630Z TRACE ---> Using 'yarn install' with YARN_ARGS
2019-12-21T11:58:21.356Z TRACE yarn install v1.10.1
2019-12-21T11:58:21.594Z TRACE warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
2019-12-21T11:58:21.657Z TRACE [1/4] Resolving packages...
2019-12-21T11:58:23.111Z TRACE [2/4] Fetching packages...
2019-12-21T11:58:53.081Z TRACE error @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.10.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "10.12.0"
2019-12-21T11:58:53.083Z TRACE error Found incompatible module
2019-12-21T11:58:53.086Z TRACE info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.  
2019-12-21T11:58:58.441Z TRACE error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-web-app:10.x   
2019-12-21T11:59:00.497Z ERROR build failed with message: Assemble script failed.
2019-12-21T11:59:00.503Z ERROR Assemble script failed.
```

i am not able to understand what I am missing here. I found that `bucharestgold/centos7-s2i-web-app` has been depreicated and tried with `npx nodeshift --strictSSL=false --dockerImage=nodeshift/ubi8-s2i-web-app --build.env YARN_ENABLED=true --deploy.env NPM_RUN="npx yarn start" --deploy.port=3000 --expose`. This is also throwing same error message.

Comment: What version of Node are you using locally?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new web-app flag feature and let nodeshift set the appropriate docker image.

Try running this command instead `npx nodeshift --web-app --build.env YARN_ENABLED=true --deploy.env NPM_RUN="npx yarn start" --deploy.port=3000`